# select and replace data using regexp in mySql

Tags: mysql, regex, regexp-replace

I am new to mySQL.I have a table with fruits (more than 10k rows). There are records of fruit names that are:

```
apples
apples_2
apples_3
...
```

I am trying to replace `_2` or `_3` ... under apples (to eliminate `_\d`) with regex in order to be able to sum another column that has budget.(was thinking that group by fruit will do the work)

I am using this code:

```
SELECT REGEXP_replace(t.fruit,'_\\d','') AS `fruitName` from Select(.....) t;
```

i have tried `\d` and `\\d` but it not correct and the problem is that when it finds the same data it answers like the next.

```
apples_2 -- applesapples 
apples_2 -- applesapplesapples 
apples_2 -- applesapplesapplesapples 
apples_2 -- applesapplesapplesapplesapples
```

What do i miss?

Comment: your query works for me, unless the problem is in he subquery (which you didn't show): https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jmJ8YsjV7PhM6DLdpCs7xe/0

Comment: There is also a question mark over the table design: why _2, _3 etc.? Presumably, these suffixes signify something that should probably be identified in another column.

Comment: the subfixes depend on previous calculations that at the top level need to be summerized (lets say different discount policies etc). The subquery that gives the t  table works properly and just makes some calculations based on names and gives this list on the left)

Comment: i also found that it does this after some row in general and not only when it finds _2

Comment: @guido - My answer explains why it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bug with `REGEXP_REPLACE()` in the particular version you are using.  Please upgrade (or downgrade.)

The changelog for 8.0.12 says, among other things:

> [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) results from one result set row could carry forward to the next row, resulting in accumulation of previous results in the current row. (Bug #27992118, Bug #90803)

8.0.14 has been released.

Comment: this is fixed though i was using community 8.0.11. I have upgraded to 8.0.12 from the installer and it works ok

Comment: i have found that regexp_replace has problem with group by is there any workaround?

Comment: @kyrpav - I have not heard of a workaround; what is the issue now that you have upgraded?  (Or do I misunderstand you?)  If it is a different query, please provide the specifics.

Comment: if i do not group by it works it replaces the names and deletes the _2,_3 but if i try to group by in order to aggregate sum numbers then it deletes all data from fruit column and gives an empty column

Comment: @kyrpav - If you would like help with that, start a new Question, use 8.0.12, and focus on its problem.